installing/building PyOpenCL to Mali GPU causes linux kernel panic: Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference
I'm trying to install PyOpenCL on a Mali G78 GPU, with the environment set to Ubuntu 22.04 (aarch64). However, I keep encountering kernel panics.
Does anyone know the reason why this is happening?
pip install pyopencl
Collecting pyopencl
  Downloading pyopencl-2024.2.7.tar.gz (470 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 471.0/471.0 KB 3.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-2.0.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (13.9 MB)
Collecting platformdirs>=2.2.0
  Downloading platformdirs-4.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting pytools>=2024.1.5
  Downloading pytools-2024.1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 88.6/88.6 KB 1.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting typing-extensions>=4.0
  Downloading typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyopencl
  Building wheel for pyopencl (pyproject.toml) ... \[ 4434.088860] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 000000000000004f
[ 4434.097741] Mem abort info:
[ 4434.103030]   ESR = 0x96000006
[ 4434.103273] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 000000000000004f
[ 4434.106672]   EC = 0x25: DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[ 4434.114951] Mem abort info:
[ 4434.120287]   SET = 0, FnV = 0
[ 4434.123102]   ESR = 0x96000006
[ 4434.126175]   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[ 4434.126183] Data abort info:
[ 4434.126194]   ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000006
[ 4434.129268]   EC = 0x25: DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[ 4434.132429]   CM = 0, WnR = 0
[ 4434.135330]   SET = 0, FnV = 0
[ 4434.139190] user pgtable: 4k pages, 39-bit VAs, pgdp=00000000f6703000
[ 4434.144521]   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[ 4434.147511] [000000000000004f] pgd=00000000bc994003, pud=00000000bc994003, pmd=0000000000000000

Capacity Problem Resolution, Document Search

that's during compilation. that shouldn't actually use any GPU, so it can't be driver issues. can you build anything else and cause your system to crash like that?

what's with the "Capacity Problem Resolution, Document Search" string at the bottom of your question?

I checked if the installation error was due to a capacity issue. The installation issue was resolved by installing version 2023.1.1, but another error occurs when running the Python code:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyopencl/init.py", line 1601, in create_some_context
platforms = get_platforms()
pyopencl._cl.LogicError: clGetPlatformIDs failed: PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR
I think that the OpenCL driver is not installed in my environment, so I am considering trying to install the GPU driver. What do you think?

I have resolved the issue. The links are recognized correctly now after adjusting them.
